# Best way to integrated Laravel 5 and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I 'm currently developing an application based on Laravel and AngularJS framework.
I wonder what is the best way to integration.
I would especially like to know where should I place the AngularJS files and how to manage the view.
Thanks you.

Comment: I'm think the best way is herre [Flexible and Easily Maintainable Laravel + Angular Material Apps](http://www.sitepoint.com/flexible-and-easily-maintainable-laravel-angular-material-apps/)

Answer (score 0):

I would place them in the public folder and use html helpers to initiate them

Comment: How to operate the views that are on the public record with those in the file resources / assets ( blade ) .

Comment: I'm think the best way is herre [Flexible and Easily Maintainable Laravel + Angular Material Apps](http://www.sitepoint.com/flexible-and-easily-maintainable-laravel-angular-material-apps/)

Answer (score 0):

Because your client will download all your javascript files, just put all your Angular app (including views) in the *public* folder !

Comment: How to operate the views that are on the public record with those in the file resources / assets ( blade ) .

Comment: I'm think the best way is herre [Flexible and Easily Maintainable Laravel + Angular Material Apps](http://www.sitepoint.com/flexible-and-easily-maintainable-laravel-angular-material-apps/)